# Is it possible to split page requests 50 / 50?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a landing page that plays a video. The client would like one video for half the users, and a different video for the second half.

I was thinking about generating doing a random number, if it's even then video 1 else video 2. I figure overtime this should end up being roughly 50 / 50. Another approach was setting a Application variable within Application_Start and using that. I was perhaps thinking I could configure something within IIS that I could evaluate when the page is requested.

The site is simple and will be served from a single source.

Is there a way to do this, before I start wasting time throwing things at the wall to see what sticks? I am not sure what to even search for.

Comment: I think your approach should be fine, just generate number between 0 and 1 and use that to choose a video to display.

Comment: it sounds like you might want to search for "A/B testing library"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate a random number where the options are limited to 2 possible outcomes then use that:

```
Random random = new Random();
var randomNumber = random.Next(0, 2);
```

The above will give you either a 0 or a 1 as output which can be used to determine one of your two paths.

I ran this 10,000 times in a little program and it came out pretty even (4948/5052).

As long as your boss isn't worried about EXACTLY even numbers I think this should be OK.

Edit: In my test program I created a new randon in each iteration of the loop, because I felt this better simulated the use-case of an ASP.NET page.

Comment: if you just use `Random`, you're going to get both results for the *same user* on page refreshes; whether that matters depends on what the aim is here; if the aim is simply "make sure both videos get seen" - then fine; if it is "find out which video gets better outcomes", you'd need a sticky A/B group, and a mechanism to record funnel completions

Comment: @MarcGravell I agree Marc, if the same user should get the same video on every visit the Random approach will not work and something more sophisticated is required. As that wasn't specifically mentioned as a requirement in the question I suggested this simple approach.

Comment: thanks guys. I don't think both videos need to be seen, just one or the other. (The spec is almost non existent... yay.) Random number it is, due to the nature of the site, page refreshes aren't likely. Besides, I can determine the number the once and add it to a session for that user.